# Trying to understand array_udiff behavior

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Let's continue. Why [array_udiff](http://php.net/array_udiff) compares values of first array after [sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28846822/1503018)?

```
$compare = function($a, $b) use(&$iteration_count)
    {
    echo("$a : $b\n");
    $iteration_count++;
    return strcmp($a, $b);
    };

$a = array('a', 'b', 'c');
$b = array('x', 'y', 'z');


$iteration_count = 0;
echo "array_udiff:" . json_encode(array_udiff($a, $b, $compare)) . "\n";
echo "iterations: $iteration_count\n\n";
```

Output

```
b : a  // sorting $a started
c : b   
y : x  // sorting $b started
z : y
a : x  // comparison started
a : b  //                    -- what for?
b : x
b : c  //                    -- what for?
c : x
array_udiff:["a","b","c"]
iterations: 9
```

http://3v4l.org/3Me8o#v500

Comment: ... to find the actual matches? Just like with your uassoc question?

Comment: @bwoebi , it's already known that 'b' > 'a' because $a already sorted. I see no pros from this repeated comparison.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't pay enough attention here…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the comparison of `A[0]` and `B[0]` it will skip all values in `A` that equal `A[0]`, because `B` doesn't have that value; see [here](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/ext/standard/array.c#4164).

To do this, it must compare at least `A[1]` against `A[0]`; you can observe this behaviour by making a small change in the first array:

```
$a = array('a', 'a', 'b', 'c');
```

Output:

```
...
a : x
a : a <-- *
a : b
b : x
b : c
c : x
```