# Trying to understand array_uintersect behavior

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Let's continue. Why [array_uintersect](http://php.net/array_uintersect) does not [compare values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28857862/1503018) of first array after [sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28846822/1503018)? By my humble opinion `array_udiff` and `array_uintersect` should have similar algorithms, but they have not. Why?

```
$compare = function($a, $b) use(&$iteration_count)
    {
    echo("$a : $b\n");
    $iteration_count++;
    return strcmp($a, $b);
    };

$a = array('a', 'b', 'c');
$b = array('x', 'y', 'z');

$iteration_count = 0;
echo "array_udiff:" . json_encode(array_udiff($a, $b, $compare)) . "\n";
echo "iterations: $iteration_count\n\n";

$iteration_count = 0;
echo "array_uintersect:" . json_encode(array_uintersect($a, $b, $compare)) . "\n";
echo "iterations: $iteration_count\n\n";
```

Output

```
b : a
c : b
y : x
z : y
a : x
a : b
b : x
b : c
c : x
array_udiff:["a","b","c"]
iterations: 9

b : a
c : b
y : x
z : y
a : x  // comparison started
b : x  // but there is no comparison to skip values
c : x
array_uintersect:[]
iterations: 7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm that's adopted by `array_intersect()` and friends is to first assume all values of the first array are present in the other arrays; during iteration it will remove elements that fail this assertion.

When an element is not found in one of the other arrays, the implementation can do two things:

1. Compare the next element against the current element and remove from the final result while they're equal (this is what diff does)
2. Compare the next element against the last inspected element of the other arrays and keep removing it from the final result until it's bigger (or the end of the array is reached).

In the case of PHP, the latter is chosen. This has a slight advantage, because it can skip values bigger than the current element but smaller than the last inspected element of the other arrays. For example:

```
$a = ['a.a0', 'a.a1', 'b.a2', 'c.a3'];
$b = ['a.c0', 'd.c1'];

function cmp_val($a, $b)
{
    echo "$a <=> $b\n";
    return strcmp($a[0], $b[0]);
}

print_r(array_uintersect($a, $b, 'cmp_val'));
```

Output:

```
...
-- intersect starts
a.a0 <=> a.c0
a.a0 <=> a.a1 <-- match
a.a1 <=> b.a2
b.a2 <=> d.c1 <-- no match
c.a3 <=> d.c1
```

As you can see, it uses the strategy of comparing within the first array if a value occurs in all other arrays, just like diff does; and the other strategy is used if the value isn't present in any of the other arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The initial sorting is in O(n log(n)) for each array, so optimizing the subsequent O(n) elimination pass would yield little gain.

This might be slower on 3 elements arrays, but will become neglectible for bigger sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I was right and wrong at the same time. Those functions have similar algorithms.

```
$compare = function($a, $b) use(&$iteration_count)
    {
    echo("$a : $b\n");
    $iteration_count++;
    return strcmp($a[0], $b[0]);
    };

$a = array('a1', 'b1', 'c1');
$b = array('a2', 'b2', 'c2');

$iteration_count = 0;
echo "array_uintersect:" . json_encode(array_uintersect($a, $b, $compare)) . "\n";
echo "iterations: $iteration_count\n\n";
```

Output

```
b1 : a1 
c1 : b1
b2 : a2
c2 : b2
a1 : a2  // comparison started
a1 : b1  // it trying to skip values after it have been matched
b1 : b2
b1 : c1
c1 : c2
array_uintersect:["a1","b1","c1"]
iterations: 9
```